# Using material UI component in storybook

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook

I'm trying to make my own component using Material UI as a starter. Then to add them to storybook.

So I'm using [storybook-addon-material-ui](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-material-ui/).

[image: Screenshoot of storybook with material ui addon]

As you can see, Material UI addon is here, but if I change them nothing happens to my component.

my **.storybook/preview.js** file:

```
import { muiTheme } from 'storybook-addon-material-ui'

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}

export const decorators = [
    muiTheme()
];
```

And if I go to the Docs tabs of a component i get this Material UI error:

> TypeError
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'borderRadius')
> Call Stack
>  push../node_modules/@mui/material/Button/Button.js.Object.ownerState.ownerState
>   vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:9051:29
> ...

Do you think it's bug from Material UI v5 ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please provide as much information as you can such as your `storybook` or `material-ui` versions, your story code, a codesandbox is the most helpful.

> if I change them nothing happens to my component.

According to its [package.json](https://github.com/react-theming/storybook-addon-material-ui/blob/version-1/package.json#L62-L68), [storybook-addon-material-ui](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-material-ui/) is made to work with :

- `"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3"`

@mui/material v5 which introduce a new styling engine that impact styles/theme management does not seem to work with this addon but i can be wrong.

> And if I go to the Docs tabs of a component i get this Material UI error

This seems to be a known storybook issue that impact `@mui/material` and is related to storybook's own theme management for "Docs" addon, [see here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24282) or [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/28716) for several temporary fixs.

In my case this worked:

```js
import { ThemeProvider as MUIThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming';

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#000000'
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#ff00ff'
        }
    }
});

export const decorators = [
    (Story) => (
        <MUIThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                {Story()}
            </ThemeProvider>
        </MUIThemeProvider>
    )
];
```

To answer the question:

> Do you think it's bug from Material UI v5 ?

I believe its more related to the addon's compatibility to material v5, or to storybook for the "Docs" issue than to material v5.